# How to execute a query when selected item changes for a drop down

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a bunch of rows and each row has a drop down with same values. When the user selects an item from the drop down in a particular row, I would like to issue a request to my REST API to update that record with the value selected.

Here is a jsbin of the working example with local data http://jsbin.com/OcAyoYo/84/edit

I'm building my view like this:

```
{{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding="App.names.content"   
}}
```

How can I add an `observe` such that it executes a query on API to save record for that ID

Answer (score 0):

just add selectionBinding to you select:

```
{{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding="App.names.content"
   selectionBinding="propertyWhereYouWantTheValueToBoPlaced"
}}
```

Comment: if you check here http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html you can find all the available options

Comment: hmm but this won't add an observe event on the selection box. Ideally I want to make a call to the server when a selection is made

Comment: you can observe when the property you binded change, then, there you can call the servers